# Rename all the files

Tags: linux, unix

How do I rename all files in the current directory with an extention of .tgz to .tar.gz?
I tried

```
find . -iname *.tgz --exec mv {} {}.tar.gz \;
```

but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Handy one is `rename .tgz .tar.gz *.tgz`

http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

Answer (score 1):

```
ls *.tgz | sed 's/\(.*\).tgz$/mv "&" "\1.tar.gz"/' | sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in *.tgz; do mv "$i" "${i/.tgz}".tar.gz; done
```

Comment: With that, you will run in problem with filenames with spaces

Comment: For filenames with spaces, simply prepend `IFS=$'\t\n';` to the start of the command. This will remove the space as a "Internal Field Separator". Do a search on `linux ifs` for more tricks with this variable.

Comment: Both expansions are quoted; there will be no problems with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

`rename` is a nice one.  But you should watch out for Debian-derivatives - they don't provide the same version as other distros.

Debian/Ubuntu/friends :

```
# rename 's/\.tgz$/\.tar.gz/ *.tgz
```

Everyone else as far as I know - http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

```
# rename .tgz .tar.gz *.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do something like this:

```
[rilindo@kvm0001 bar]$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 rilindo cgred 4096 Oct 20 23:16 .
drwxr-xr-x. 8 rilindo cgred 4096 Oct 20 23:10 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 rilindo cgred    0 Oct 20 23:15 bar.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 rilindo cgred    0 Oct 20 23:15 baz.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 rilindo cgred    0 Oct 20 23:16 foo.txt
[rilindo@kvm0001 bar]$ for i in `find . -type f -iname "*.txt"`; do j=`echo $i | sed 's/.txt$/.doc/'`; mv $i $j; done
[rilindo@kvm0001 bar]$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x. 2 rilindo cgred 4096 Oct 20 23:16 .
drwxr-xr-x. 8 rilindo cgred 4096 Oct 20 23:10 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 rilindo cgred    0 Oct 20 23:15 bar.doc
-rw-r--r--. 1 rilindo cgred    0 Oct 20 23:15 baz.doc
-rw-r--r--. 1 rilindo cgred    0 Oct 20 23:16 foo.doc
[rilindo@kvm0001 bar]$
```

So with this command string:

```
for i in `find . -type f -iname "*.txt"`; do j=`echo $i | sed 's/.txt$/.doc/'`; mv $i $j; done
```

I get the list of files and for each element, assign the file name with a new extension to a variable and rename each file to that variable.

This is, of course, probably not a perfect script, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: It didn't work if file name including spaces.

Comment: That is true. Hence, my caveat. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend 'mmv'. Pretty simple and less error-prone than 'for' expressions.

Comment: Hi Peter, welcome to Serverfault. Can you provide either more information about `mmv` and perhaps a link to this utility? I think many of us are unfamiliar with this utility.

Comment: @StefanLasiewski, see link @ http://serverfault.com/questions/323527/rename-all-the-files/323534#323534 — it mentions mvv in "See also" section.

Comment: mmv can be found in the ubuntu universe repository. After enabling the repo, one can install it in the standard way by issuing 'sudo apt-get install mmv'